# Using Cauchy's integral formula to solve $\int_{|z| = 2} \frac{e^z}{z^2(z-1)}\,dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

On p. 116 in Complex Analysis by Gamelin, he has just introduced some examples of the application of the Cauchy Integral Formula (CIF). He then considers the integral $$\int_{|z| = 2} \frac{e^z}{z^2(z-1)}\,dz$$ which cannot immediately be solved using CIF. He introduces a way to solve this by cutting out two discs of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $0$, and $1$ to obtain, $$\int_{|z| = 2} \frac{e^z}{z^2(z-1)}\,dz = \int_{|z| = \epsilon} \frac{e^z}{z^2(z-1)}\,dz + \int_{|z-1| = \epsilon} \frac{e^z}{z^2(z-1)}\,dz.$$

What makes it ok to do this cut out of discs? He do not mention his reasoning.My guess is that since we want the theorem to be applicable we need to take care of the singularities in some way and I do agree with him in applying the theorem to the two new integrals around the two epsilon discs. Is the "formal" argument for doing what he did that since the discs with radius $\epsilon$ union with the disc $\{|z| = 2\}$1 is a bounded domain with piecewise smooth boundary, and since the integrands $f(z) = \frac{e^z}{z-1}$ and $f(z) = \frac{e^z}{z^2}$ are analytic on $\{|z|=\epsilon\}$ and  $\{|z-1|=\epsilon\}$ respectively, we can be guaranteed that *it* works? However, what is meant by *it*? Do we let $\epsilon \to 0$?

All help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: $O$ is homotopic to $oo$ then you can let the radius of both disk $\to 0$. The same argument shows that the Cauchy integral theorem/formula works even when the curve isn't a simple closed curve, for example with the annulus $U =\{ 1/4 < |z| < 3/4\}$ then $\int_{\partial U} \frac{e^z}{z^2(z-1)}\,dz=0$ because the function is analytic on $\overline{U}$

Comment: So you are saying that the disc $D = \{|z|=2\}$, and the punctured disc $D_\epsilon = \{|z|=2\}-\{|z|=\epsilon\}-\{|z-1|=\epsilon\}$ are homotopic and this is so because when we let $\epsilon \to 0$, $D_\epsilon \to D$?

Comment: I realize what you mean now. The two epsilon-discs are removed from the original domain to create a new domain where the integrand is analytic in. This yield an integral that will equal to zero by cauchys ’s theorem and rewriting it we got what the author used!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to calculate $$I = \int_{\partial D} \frac{e^z}{z^2(z-1)}dz$$ where $D = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| \leq 2\}$.

Since the integrand $\frac{e^z}{z^2(z-1)}$ has two singularities in $D$, namely, at $z = 0$, and $z = 1$, we remove two epsilon-discs, containing these points, from $D$, in order to get a domain where the integrand $\frac{e^z}{z^2(z-1)}$ is analytic. This we do in order to apply Cauchy's theorem ($\int_{}f(z)dz = 0$ whenever $f(z)$ is analytic.)

We now consider the integral $$I_\epsilon = \int_{D_\epsilon}\frac{e^z}{z^2(z-1)}dz$$ where $D_\epsilon$ is the punctured disc, $D\epsilon = D-\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| \leq \epsilon\}-\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z-1| \leq \epsilon\}$.

By Cauchy's theorem, $$0 = \int_{D_\epsilon}\frac{e^z}{z^2(z-1)}dz = \int_{D} \frac{e^z}{z^2(z-1)}dz - \int_{|z| = \epsilon}\frac{e^z}{z^2(z-1)}dz - \int_{|z-1| = \epsilon} \frac{e^z}{z^2(z-1)}dz \iff \int_{D} \frac{e^z}{z^2(z-1)}dz = \int_{|z| = \epsilon}\frac{e^z}{z^2(z-1)}dz + \int_{|z-1| = \epsilon} \frac{e^z}{z^2(z-1)}dz$$

We can apply Cauchy's integral formula, $$f^{(m)}(z) = \frac{m!}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial D} \frac{f(w)}{(w-z)^{m+1}}dw,$$

to each summand of the integral,

$$I = \int_{|z| = \epsilon}\frac{e^z}{z^2(z-1)}dz + \int_{|z-1| = \epsilon} \frac{e^z}{z^2(z-1)}dz = 2\pi i \frac{d}{dz}\left[\frac{e^z}{z-1}\right]\biggr\rvert_{z = 0} + 2\pi i \left[\frac{e^z}{z^2}\right]\biggr\rvert_{z = 1} = 2\pi i (-2) + 2\pi i (e) = 2\pi i(e-2).$$

Comment: Cute, so you just accepted your own answer with a typo at the end? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=residue+of+e%5Ez%2F(z%5E2(z-1))+at+z%3D1 and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=residue+of+e%5Ez%2F(z%5E2(z-1))+at+z%3D0

Comment: I have not learned about residuals yet but thanks for pointing out the typo. I realized I had accidentally differentiated the second summand.

Answer (score 1):

*An easier version*. Use partial fraction decomposition 
$$\frac{1}{z^2(z-1)}=-\frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z-1}$$ 
then
$$\int\limits_{|z|=2}\frac{e^z}{z^2(z-1)}dz=
-\int\limits_{|z|=2}\frac{e^z}{z^2}dz - \int\limits_{|z|=2}\frac{e^z}{z}dz + \int\limits_{|z|=2}\frac{e^z}{z-1}dz$$
and now you can apply [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula):
$$f^{(n)}(a)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}dz$$
where $f(z)=e^z$, for each of the three parts.
$$\int\limits_{|z|=2}\frac{e^z}{z^2(z-1)}dz=
-2\pi i f'(0)-2\pi i f(0) + 2\pi i f(1)=
 2\pi i (e-2)$$